# Excel VBA, Autofilter with the output from a loop

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, filter

```
Sub Projektlaufzeit()

Dim Datum1 As Date, msg As String
Dim Datum2 As Date
Dim Rest As Long
Dim Projektname As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim ber As Range


Projektname = Range("A2")
Datum1 = Date
'Datum2 = Tabelle1.Range("C2")


c = Sheets("tabelle1").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

For i = 2 To c

Projektname = Cells(i, 1)
Datum2 = Cells(i, 3)
Rest = DateDiff("d", Datum1, Datum2)


    If Rest > 7 And Rest < 30 Then MsgBox "something"
    If Rest >= 0 And Rest <= 7 Then MsgBox "something"
    If Rest <= 0 Then MsgBox "something"

Next i


Dim FilterArray
Dim List As Range
Set List = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")

List.AutoFilter
FilterArray = Array(Projektname)

List.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array(FilterArray)


End Sub
```

So that is my code so far. I have a Loop which tells me when a certain project will come to an end. That works so far.
The next step is, that the macro will autofilter all projects that have a remaining duration of < 30 days.

In my code obviously only the last project that was affected by the loop will be filtered. Is it possible to create an array with all affected projects? 
I attached a screenshot of the Excel Worksheet.
Thanks in advance.[image: Worksheet]

Comment: Can you use a 'helper' column that calculates this as a `TRUE` or `FALSE` outcome and then the filter is simple ?

Comment: should be possible, will try. Mind helping though?

Answer (score 0):

If you imagine that all your dates are numbers and your target is to create an array of the values in column A, that
correspond to some condition, then this is a possible input:

[image]

With the code below, the condition is translated as:
*Projects with remaining duration less or equal than 2 days and not finished with today's date.*

```
Option Explicit

Sub ProjectTime()

    Dim lngDateToday            As Long
    Dim lngRemainingDuration    As Long
    Dim lngLastRow              As Long
    Dim lngCounter              As Long
    Dim varProjects()           As Variant
    Dim blnFirst                As Boolean

    blnFirst = True
    lngDateToday = Range("D2")
    lngRemainingDuration = Range("E2")
    lngLastRow = 13
    ReDim varProjects(0)

    For lngCounter = 2 To lngLastRow
        If Cells(lngCounter, 3) < (lngDateToday + lngRemainingDuration) And _
                                Cells(lngCounter, 3) >= lngDateToday Then

            If Not blnFirst Then
                ReDim Preserve varProjects(UBound(varProjects) + 1)
            End If
            blnFirst = False
            varProjects(UBound(varProjects)) = Cells(lngCounter, 1)
        End If

    Next lngCounter

    For lngCounter = LBound(varProjects) To UBound(varProjects)
        Debug.Print varProjects(lngCounter)
    Next lngCounter

End Sub
```

Thus, projects E,G and I (highlighted) are the one matched and added to the array of values. As far as we are not using a collection, but an array, I am redim-ing and preserving on every step (except for the first one).

To filter the array, you need to add the array as a parameter to the filter. Add the following to the end of the code:

```
Dim List As Range
Set List = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
List.AutoFilter
List.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Array(varProjects), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

This is how it should look like:

[image]

Comment: I do not quite understand how to do the sorting then?

Comment: @StB - I hope that you mean filtering, not sorting. See the edit.

Comment: Yes i meant filtering. However it only filters things that have a postive remaining duration. If the project "will end in -600 days", meaning it ended 600 days ago it does not appear filtered

Comment: @StB - I don't get it, come up with some samples & screenshots.

Comment: @StB - and which lines should be present on the filter as well?

Comment: all lines that have a remaining duration < 30 days. Even if it is negative. If you could show me a code how that works and explain it a bit that would help a lot. I could adapt it then for similar problems in the future. 

I'm trying to build something that lets the user decide what should be filtered (<0, <7, <30 remaining days etc.). But first i need to understand how the filtering works

Comment: @StB - the filtering is here:         `If Cells(lngCounter, 3) < (lngDateToday + lngRemainingDuration) And Cells(lngCounter, 3) >= lngDateToday Then` Try playing a bit with the conditions, remove the `And` and see what you will get.